# How do i add percentage an Access query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-query

My teacher wants us to add 10% to the net income in our query and he told me he can't help us in out projects but I don't understand how to do that?[the picture shows the query I am attempting to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0cxa.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  See here on how to post questions that are likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this case you definitely want to post your code in-line.

Comment: I answered, but yes.  Doing your homework for you is not really what this is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to an update query.

For `Field:` put `[Net Income]`

For `Update To:` put `[Net Income] * 1.1`